# i need to print these two lines when a button is clicked?(See below)

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

Issue date :24/7/15
Return date : 25/8/15

Can I use `OnClickListener` to show multiple dates? Or do I use the function : `public void Buttonclicked(View view)`?

Comment: Next time, try to do the project on your own. That's why its given to you and not to us

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
 date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           //Un hide already hidden textviews
           issue_date.setText("Issue date :24/7/15");
           issue_date.setVisibilty(0);
           return_date.setText("Return date : 25/8/15 1");
           return_date.setVisibilty(0);
        }
    });
```